# Do user threads and kernel threads correspond to thread-level library and kernel-level library in any of the following ways?

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads

From [Operating System Concepts](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Ejbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/4_Threads.html) by Abraham Silberschatz, Greg Gagne, and Peter Baer Galvin, here is discussion of user threads vs kernel threads:

> support for threads may be provided either at the user level, for user
> threads, or by the kernel, for kernel threads.
>
> - **User threads** are
>   supported above the kernel and are managed without kernel support,
> - **kernel threads** are supported and managed directly by the
>   operating system. Virtually all contemporary operating
>   systems—including Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, and Solaris— support
>   kernel threads.
>
> Ultimately, a relationship must exist between **user threads** and **kernel
> threads**. In this section, we look at three common ways of establishing
> such a relationship: the many-to-one model, the one-to-one model, and
> the many-to- many model.

and here is discussion of user-level library vs kernel-level library for creating and managing threads:

> A thread library provides the programmer with an API for creating and
> managing threads. There are two primary ways of implementing a thread
> library.
>
> - The ﬁrst approach is to provide **a library entirely in user space with no kernel support**. All code and data structures for the library
>   exist in user space. This means that invoking a function in the
>   library results in a local function call in user space and not a
>   system call.
> - The second approach is to implement **a kernel-level library supported directly by the operating system**. In this case, code and data
>   structures for the library exist in kernel space. Invoking a function
>   in the API for the library typically results in a system call to the
>   kernel.
>
> Three main thread libraries are in use today: POSIX Pthreads, Windows,
> and Java. **Pthreads, the threads extension of the POSIX standard, may
> be provided as either a user-level or a kernel-level library**. The
> Windows thread library is a kernel-level library available on Windows
> systems. The Java thread API allows threads to be created and managed
> directly in Java programs. However, because in most instances the JVM
> is running on top of a host operating system, the Java thread API is
> generally implemented using a thread library available on the host
> system. This means that on Windows systems, Java threads are typically
> implemented using the Windows API; UNIX and Linux systems often use
> Pthreads.

Do user threads and kernel threads correspond to thread-level library and kernel-level library in any of the following ways?

- Does a user-level library necessarily create and manage only user threads but no kernel threads?
- Does a kernel-level library necessarily create and manage only kernel threads but no user threads?
- Are user threads necessarily created and managed by user-level libraries not by kernel-level libraries?
- Are kernel threads necessarily created and managed by kernel-level libraries not by user-level libraries?

The book says "Pthreads, the threads extension of the POSIX standard, may be provided as either a user-level or a kernel-level library."

- Is PThread a kernel-level library in Linux and a user-level library in Windows?
- Does PThread create and manage user threads or kernel threads according to the definitions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Does a user-level library necessarily create and manage only user threads but no kernel threads?

It seems, that here phrase 'user-level library' refers to library that doesn't rely on kernel syscalls that allow creating and managing threads, so by definition it cannot create kernel threads.

The idea here is that the kernel remains unaware that you are doing threading inside your process. Major limitation of this approach is that such proccess can't use more than one processor core at the time.

> Does a kernel-level library necessarily create and manage only kernel threads but no user threads?

'Kernel-level library' is a bit of a misnomer. Library is a user-space concept. It is possible that in some cases there is one-to-one correspondence between library functions and kernel syscalls, but it is often not the most practical solution.

In Linux, there is a `clone` syscall that creates a new process. This new process can share memory, file descriptors and other resources with parent. At high-level, we would often refer to such processes as threads within one process. Directly playing with syscalls is often a needless complexity and makes portability difficult, so instead a user-space library is usually used.

Commonly used pthread implementations are 'kernel-level' in a sense that pthread threads correspond 1-1 to system threads, however in many cases library functions calls do not need to correspond 1-1 to syscalls. In particular, the most commonly used functions are specifically designed such that they don't need to use syscalls in most cases. It helps performance.

It is possible to implement pthread in other ways, but this appears to be most practical. It leaves most options at the hands of the library user, as there is no extra level of indirection between threads inside or outside.

> Are user threads necessarily created and managed by user-level libraries not by kernel-level libraries?

'User threads' are just process-like constructs that are not recognized by the kernel. It is possible that 'kernel-level' library would use something like that. It is also possible to implement them directly without using any libraries whatsoever.

> Are kernel threads necessarily created and managed by kernel-level libraries not by user-level libraries?

Creation of kernel thread relies on a syscall that creates a thread. In most cases it would be used within library, but in principle you can invoke them directly.

Comment: Thanks. In Linux, what are the threads created and managed by PThread: kernel threads, or user threads with one-to-one model with respect to kernel threads?

Comment: @Tim, I don't think there is really much difference between these two descriptions. Technically, the threads are visible to library user, so you can call them user threads, but the 1-1 correspondence allows us to drop the distinction and just call them threads.

Answer (score 1):

The nomenclature quoted is confusing IMO. First, linux, and Windows (and most other OSes I have looked at or worked on) do not have "libraries" for the implementation of their internal interfaces and data structures. Furthermore, a library is just a body of code bundled together for convenience. Hence describing a library as some fundamental and *necessary* building block (at either kernel- or user-level) is misguided IMO.

Having said that, in practice, all systems *do* of course have libraries as a convenience to assist programs with getting to operating system services and/or related bodies of code. For one thing, system calls are typically implemented by loading arguments into registers and executing some sort of trap instruction to switch the processor into kernel mode. Since almost all programs are written in a high-level language, loading things in registers and executing trap instructions cannot generally be done directly. So, it's difficult to see how a kernel thread implementation - in general - would be "managed" without any user-level library whatsoever. My point is that essentially *all* kernel-thread implementations will need assistance from a user-level library to one extent or another.

A purely user-level thread implementation, on the other hand, *could* be implemented *solely* within a library. Indeed that would be the logical way to structure it.

Threads are implemented at a kernel level for both linux and Windows. The native Windows API has its own thread creation and management facilities reached through the Windows system call interface. Linux also has its own mechanisms implemented via *its* system call interface. The posix threads (pthreads) interface is implemented as a library on top of both of those.

Generally, pthreads is considered the *native* interface to linux threads though that is not literally true. The facilities provided by pthreads include thread creation, destruction, and management as well as a number of mechanisms used in synchronization and interprocess communication. The underlying system calls used to implement this, though, include critical building blocks like `clone` and `futex` that are not generally accessed directly. They are used by a user-level layer to provide the pthreads-specified behavior.

Windows has its own unique thread management API that is built into the "win32" library and uses Windows-specific system calls to implement its behavior. The details are all different (from linux) and it does not conform to the pthreads specification. However, you can install a *second* library atop the native one that adapts the Windows API into a pthreads-compatible interface (it consists largely of wrappers around the Windows functions).

So, for both systems, the pthreads library creates and manages the various pthread-specified objects with the assistance of the respective OS kernel (and using a kernel-thread implementation in both cases).

Finally, it should be noted that Windows also has a true "user-level" thread implementation, which they have named "fiber". There is no analog in linux for that (though other Unix implementations in the past have included user-level threads implementations). And as far as I know, the pthreads library for Windows does not provide access to the fiber implementation.

Comment: Thanks. In Windows, is pthread implemented using one-to-one or many-to-one model (see https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/4_Threads.html for the definitions of the models), i.e. is there only one or more pthread threads corresponding to one Windows kernel thread? (Note: in Linux, there is only one pthread thread corresponding to one lightweight process, so one-to-one model, if I am correct)

Comment: You are correct about linux, and it is also one-to-one in the pthreads-win32 implementation. It is a straight-forward wrapper around the windows thread library. You can find the source code for it at ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/sources